# How can i solve this Viewport.dart problem?

Tags: flutter

*When I am trying to run project always show me this problem. I dont know why I face this problem.
If anyone know , Or any way to solve the problem - just tell me please.
How can I solve this probelm.*

When I am trying to run project always show me this problem. I dont know why I face this problem.

If anyone know , Or any way to solve the problem - just tell me please.

How can I solve this probelm.

```
   Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1820 in debug mode...
    lib\main.dart:1
    : Error: Expected ';' after this.
    ../…/rendering/viewport.dart:1375
                    ErrorSummary('Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.'),
                                                                                ^
    : Error: Expected an identifier, but got ','.
    ../…/rendering/viewport.dart:1375
    Try inserting an identifier before ','.
                    ErrorSummary('Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.'),
                                                                                 ^
    : Error: Expected ';' after this.
    ../…/rendering/viewport.dart:1375
                    ErrorSummary('Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.'),
                                                                                 ^
    : Error: Unexpected token ','.
    ../…/rendering/viewport.dart:1375
                    ErrorSummary('Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.'),
                                                                                 ^
    
    : Error: Expected ';' after this.
    ../…/rendering/viewport.dart:1381
                    ),
                    ^
    : Error: Expected an identifier, but got ','.
    ../…/rendering/viewport.dart:1381
    Try inserting an identifier before ','.
                    ),
    : Error: Expected an identifier, but got ','.
    ../…/rendering/viewport.dart:1381
    Try inserting an identifier before ','.
                    ),
                     ^
    : Error: Expected ';' after this.
    ../…/rendering/viewport.dart:1381
                    ),
                     ^
    : Error: Unexpected token ','.
    ../…/rendering/viewport.dart:1381
                    ),
                     ^
    3
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * Where:
    Script 'C:\Users\ramja\Documents\DartConfig\flutterSDK\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
    > Process 'command 'C:\Users\ramja\Documents\DartConfig\flutterSDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 2m 0s
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
    Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: can you share your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `;` instead of `,`

```
 ErrorSummary('Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.');
```

Answer (score 0):

view port error of unbound height generally comes when you don't define any height for your flexible widget. Put your flexible widget inside SizedBox or container with height. Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have done ay changes to viewport.dart file.

You can easyly revert the changes if you have configured any version controle to your project.

I have reverted the changes to "viewport.dart" by simply clicking on revert the changes in VS Code.

Simply revert from `,` to `;` where the framwwork says `^`

Comment: You can improve your answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).